# Check window close is available

Tags: javascript, browser

We can't close browser window if we didn't open a window. More about this is here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close

I want to check close option is available or works. I want to use this option for older browser. I don't want to check browser version but use more clever condition for that. The behavior which I want is:

- if this event is available run and close window
- if not available display message and hide button

I want check that after loaded page.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Check for window.opener.

```
if(window.opener !== null) //it was opened by JS, so you can close it
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to check whether the window was opened by Javascript. In my experience the browser never gives an error for trying to close a window. So just write something like this:

```
window.close(); 
// If it worked, the next statement will never execute.
// Else,
setTimeout(function() {
    alert("Please close the window!");
}, 1);
```

Here `setTimeout` ensures that the `window.close` is executed before the `alert` statement.

Of course, you can wrap the `window.close()` in a `try...catch` anyway to avoid issues if browsers decide to throw an exception on that in future.

Comment: I tested. Alert will be execute before browser will be close.

Comment: Right, I hadn't tested that. Turns out you have to wait for `window.close` to execute. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just call window.close() to close a window. We can check if a window is closed or not using `window.closed`.